# How do you set an item in a .plist with PlistBuddy?

Tags: unix, plist

I'm having trouble tracing through a .plist with PlistBuddy and change it in the command line, I know the format is similar to, "/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :items:2:assets: www.test.com" ./Test.plist" But I keep getting an error of Does not Exist. What would the path be to change url?

```
<dict>
  <key>items</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
    <key>assets</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>kind</key>
        <string>software-package</string>
        <key>url</key>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `:items:0:assets:0:url`

Comment: my .plist is :<array>
  <dict>
   <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
   <string>Editor</string>
   <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
   <array>
    <string>123</string>
   </array>
  </dict>
  <dict>
   <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
   <string>Editor</string>
   <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
   <string></string>
   <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
   <array>
    <string>abc</string>
   </array>
  </dict>   then I run /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleURLTypes:0:CFBundleURLSchemes. It returns Set: Cannot Perform Set On Containers

Answer (score 0):

escraffod's solution worked for me.

Here's the complete solution for the problem:

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set items:0:assets:0:url http://www.test.com" ./Test.plist

Comment: my .plist is 
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>123</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        
then I run  
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleURLTypes:0:CFBundleURLSchemes
It returns

```

Set: Cannot Perform Set On Containers

```